# How to emulate strongly typed enum in C?

Tags: c, enums

In C++03, it is possible to emulate [strongly typed enum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Strongly_typed_enumerations) by putting it in a class (or a namespace ) :

```
struct MyEnum
{
  enum enumName
  {
    VALUE_1 = 1,
    VALUE_2,
  };
};
```

and to use it :

```
MyEnum::enumName v = MyEnum::VALUE_1;
```

Is it possible to do something similar in C? If yes, how?

---

I tried like this, but off course that doesn't work :

```
struct A
{
  enum aa
  {
    V1 = 5
  };
};

int main()
{
  A::aa a1 = A::V1;
  enum A::aa a2 = A::V1;
  struct A::aa a3 = A::V1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: there are no namespaces and classes in C - so you cannot..

Comment: There are probably some things to do with variadic macros in C99, by replacing the scope operator by an underscore. But in plain C89, I don't think it's possible.

Comment: @AJG85: structs in C are not the same as structs in C++, in C++ they are *classes* while in C they are not.

Comment: @Morwenn C99 solution is fine

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas True, in C++ a struct is a class with default public scope instead of default private scope. However a C struct is a data container which is still good enough for OP albeit less convenient.

Comment: `A::aa a1 == A::V1;` you meant assignment, right?

Comment: Is it OK if the assignment gives a warning, not an error?

Comment: @Mr.Anubis Right. fixed. Thanks

Comment: @AJG85: How is a C struct *good enough* for OP? Can you provide that as an answer? --I *believe* it isn't, without *scope-operator* how would you access the values of the enum type within the struct? (You cannot) and the enumerators will be pushed to the common identifier space, which clearly does not meet the *strongly typed* part of the question --which is actually **the** question. C structs are nothing like C++ structs for this particular purpose as they **don't define a scope for the enum**

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Sure. With warning you can still compile.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I was thinking a struct containing const ints perhaps. I don't have a C compiler handy to test with however and I'm much more familiar with C++ ... Eric's answer below looks plausible as well.

Comment: @AJG85: C is quite more limited than C++ in many things. I don't think a struct containing const ints would cut it either. The constants inside the struct cannot be (IIRC) `static` (in the class-level C++ sense) which means that to access the values you would have to create an instance (high cost), and without constructors or a way to provide the value that would have to be done through either explicit aggregate initialization (again C++ term) or a function returning the struct (more cost), and the constants would not serve as a compile time constants (constant expressions)

Comment: My point is that tuxtimo comment might not have been explicit enough, but your first comment is completely irrelevant to the question and just adds noise (as demonstrated by 4 people that uptick it, probably considering that it made any difference...) :)

Comment: Excellent points, I didn't think it all the way through I guess it really wouldn't work anywhere near as well as C++. C11 has changes for anonymous structs and unions which might be useful for nesting but I don't think it adds any type safety ;-(

Comment: @tuxtimo: actually, C does provide four different namespaces for identifiers.  One is for labels, one is for struct, union, and enum *tags*, one is for struct and union *members*, and the last is for all other identifiers, including enumeration constants.

Answer (score 7):

Here's my solution. Has a few advantages over @Eric's design:

- Supports equality testing (e.g. `A_VALUE_0 == value`)
- Doesn't rely on C99's compound literals
- Can cast to assign an improper value to a enum.

Disadvantages:

- Flags do not work (e.g. `A_VALUE_0 | A_VALUE_1`)
- Cannot be `switch`'d
- Can confuse the IDE on where the error lines are when testing for equality (e.g. `A_VALUE_0 == B_VALUE_1`)

Notes:

- NEVER dereference a pointer of this type. Will cause crashes faster than a Lamborghini

Here's the implementation (compiled with `-Werror` & `-pedantic`):

```
typedef struct A { char empty[1]; } *A; // we use 'empty' so that we don't get a warning that empty structs are a GNU extension
#define A_VALUE_0 ((A) 0x1)
#define A_VALUE_1 ((A) 0x2)
#define A_VALUE_2 ((A) 0x4)

typedef struct B { char empty[1]; } *B;

#define B_VALUE_0 ((B) 0x0)
#define B_VALUE_1 ((B) 0x1)
#define B_VALUE_2 ((B) 0x2)

int main()
{
    A a = A_VALUE_0;

    int equal = (a == A_VALUE_1); // works!
    int euqal = (a == B_VALUE_1) // doesn't work

    A flags = A_VALUE_0 | A_VALUE_1; // doesn't work!

    switch (a) { // doesn't work
        case A_VALUE_0:
            puts("value 0");
            break;
        case A_VALUE_1:
            puts("value 1");
            break;
        case A_VALUE_2:
            puts("value 2");
            break;
        default:
            puts("unknown value");
            break;
    } // doesn't work

    // casting works for assignment:
    A b = (A) (B_VALUE_2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1, some comments: I still would go with an `enum` at the base to declare the values. This is easier to maintain if values are added e.g. To avoid spooky integer to pointer warnings for some oldish compilers you should go through `uintptr_t`, something like `((B)(uintptr_t) 0x2)`. To declare pointers to a `struct` you don't even have to declare the struct itself, `typedef struct spooky_struct* A` would suffice.

Comment: This approach relies on a cooperative implementation defined behavior "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. ..., the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation." C17dr  § 6.3.2.3 5  Coding on the edges.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
// Declare A to use for an enumeration, and declare some values for it.
typedef struct { int i; } A;
#define A0  ((A) { 0 })
#define A1  ((A) { 1 })

// Declare B to use for an enumeration, and declare some values for it.
typedef struct { int i; } B;
#define B0  ((B) { 0 })
#define B1  ((B) { 1 })


void foo(void)
{
    // Initialize A.
    A a = A0;

    // Assign to A.
    a = A1;

    // Assign a value from B to A.
    a = B0; // Gets an error.
}
```

That gives you some typing, but it may be a nuisance, depending on what other operations you want to perform with the enumeration and its values.

Comment: The assignment uses a C99 feature ([compound literals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#Compound_literals)) but the rest also works in C89.

Comment: @Shahbaz This worked with `gcc -ansi` (with gcc 4.1.2) for me.

Comment: @rwos, ah yes. I remember now that I couldn't write it (in some code of mine) because I was compiling with g++, not that it was C11. My bad.

Comment: The big problem here is that testing for equality won't work i.e. `A a = A0 ; A b = A0 ; bool foo = (a == b);` doesn't compile.  Also, you can't use variables of type A in switches.

Comment: @EricFinn gcc with `-ansi -pedantic` displays a warning ("ISO C90 forbids compound literals"). On the other hand: who uses C89/90-only compiles anymore? :-)

Comment: `gcc -std=c99` to the rescue.

Comment: @rwos I've had to, just last year. Many corporations don't upgrade their software that often, and a certain vendor was still only supporting C89 in their 2010 release.

Answer (score 3):

As C doesn't provide namespaces, you can use prefixes instead.

```
enum MyEnum {
    MyEnumA = 1,
    MyEnumB,
    MyEnumC
};

enum OtherEnum {
    OtherEnumA = 1,
    OtherEnumB
};
```

Then, for conciseness in variable declarations, you may declare types for your enum, like this:

```
typedef enum MyEnum MyEnum;
typedef enum OtherEnum OtherEnum;
```

Finally, If you don't want to allow implicit conversions of `OtherEnumB` to the `MyEnum` type, Clang provides the `-Wenum-conversion` flag (I don't think there's a similar flag in GCC unfortunately).

```
/tmp/test.c:24:20: warning: implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum OtherEnum' to different enumeration type 'MyEnum' (aka 'enum MyEnum') [-Wenum-conversion]
    MyEnum value = OtherEnumB;
           ~~~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

This has the advantage to be simple, easy to understand and to work well with your (mine, at least) IDE's autocompletion.

Comment: I know it's 3 years later, so no worries if there's no reply. Were you using g++? With gcc, I just can't make this work. I've tried versions 4.6 and 4.7, and have also added -Wextra, -Wall -Wenum-compare.

Comment: I used Clang. I assumed GCC would also emit warnings for implicit conversions between `enum` types but I may have been wrong. It looks like GCC only warns on comparisons when using `-Wenum-compare`.

Comment: Ah, right. It works as you described with clang. I've also tried a more recent gcc, and still no warning. There are also bug reports and discussions over that, but it seems gcc developers are happy with status quo, because "standard says all this is valid".