# How to warn when assigning or performing arithmetic with different enum types in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc, enums, type-conversion, gcc-warning

While I'm aware this is valid C not to differentiate between enum types.

GCC does have `-Wenum-compare` (which I'm using) and works as expected.

I tried using `-Wconversion` but this doesn't make any difference.

How can assignments and arithmetic operators (`+`/`-`/`&`/`|`... etc) also generate warnings? (assignment, or and... etc)

```
{
    enum Foo f = SOME_VALUE;
    enum Bar b = SOME_OTHER_VALUE;

    if (f != b) {
        /* this warns! */
    }

    f = b;  /* <-- how to warn about this? */
    f |= b;  /* .. and this? */

}
```

---

Notes:

- Switching to C++ is not an option *(as suggested in other answers)*.
- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669454) is closely related, however its not a duplicate because it's about passing arguments instead of arithmetic.

Comment: even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` it doesn't issue the warning. I guess you'll have to use extra check tools (which is bummer because nothing beats using the compiler)

Comment: `-Wenum-compare` is included in `Wall`, but it only checks comparisons (as stated). You'd like `Wenum-assign` :)

Comment: With an `enum` being not much more than syntactic sugar for named integer values, there's not much you can do. Just out of academic interest, I once created some [enum classes like code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/96069/77356), but I doubt it's useful in practice.

Comment: GCC have been adding useful & practical warnings (`-Wimplicit-fallthrough` for example). Perhaps they would consider `-Wenum-conversion`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make gcc warn about passing wrong enum to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669454/how-to-make-gcc-warn-about-passing-wrong-enum-to-a-function)

Comment: @jean-françois-fabre - yes I read this question first, but its about passing function args, not arithmetic or mixing enums in expressions.

Comment: @ideasman42 regarding your edit: Jean-François isn't suggesting to **switch** to C++, just to (ab)use a C++ compiler for an additional code checking step...

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize, that that could be made more clear. Even so, we use enough C-only features this wont work, or at least it wont work on a project wide basis (large number of source files) - where it would be most useful.

Comment: I'm suggesting to build a checker tool out of g++ and your makefile switched to g++. Compile all objects done that way to the trash and keep only interesting messages (and filtering out other errors related to C-only features) using a good `grep` command. That's what _I_ would do.

Comment: and the linked question also works for your case.

Comment: Only in trivial cases, for large C projects (which make some use of C11) its impractical *(which is why I note using C++ isn't an option).* The example is of course a trivial case but that's just to communicate the intent.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28484481/1282773), only clang supports the desired behavior.

There are [some approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903625/how-to-emulate-strongly-typed-enum-in-c) to emulate strongly typed enums in C, but they seem to have various limitations.