# How can I convert enum in C++ code into C

Tags: c++, c, class, enums, structure

I am converting C++ code to C code. Here is the code which needs to be converted-

```
struct new{
   enum new_enum:uint8_t {
       head = 1,
       tail = 2,
       data = 3,
   };
};
```

How to convert this? Can someone explain what is uint8_t in enum? Is it assigning all variables to uint8_t?

Comment: `converting C++ code to C code` is quite unclear. Do you want to convert the the enum value to its underlying integral value ?

Answer (score 2):

The code you provide cannot compile in C++, since the struct name is `new`.

Anyway, you can try to just drop the `:uint8_t`. This will change the strongly typed `enum` to a standard C one. If you are lucky everything will work. If in any other point you have an use of `head`, `tail` or `data`, it won't work. You can do this:

```
enum new_enum {
    new_enum_head = 1,
    new_enum_tail = 2,
    new_enum_data = 3,
};
```

Ugly, but likely to work. Of course the `enum` will have to go out of the `struct` it was defined in. That again can cause a lot of grief, but less likely.

Answer (score 0):

> I am converting C++ code to C code.

This this seems like a strange direction to take.

There is no direct conversion here. Typed enums are a c++ feature.

There is a similar question here: [How to emulate strongly typed enum in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903625/how-to-emulate-strongly-typed-enum-in-c)